What kinds of even numbers have odd aliquot sums?
A number's aliquot sum, $s(n)$, is defined as the sum of the number's divisors, not including itself. (In other words, $s(n) = \sigma(n) - n$.) Even numbers generally have even aliquot sums: if $x$ has $n$ odd prime factors then $x$ will generally have $2^n$ odd factors (including $1$). I say generally because there are exceptions; for example, powers of $2$ have $1$ as their only odd factor, and thus have odd aliquot sums. Squares of even numbers also have odd aliquot sums.
My question is thus:

Are numbers of the form $2^n$ and/or $(2n)^2$ where $n > 0$ the only even numbers that have odd aliquot sums? If not, what other types of numbers exhibit this property, and why?

I acknowledge the existence of this question, but my question talks about even numbers, not odd numbers, and is asking for exceptions to a rule instead of a rule itself.
Thanks for your help!

If $n$ is even then $s(n)$ is odd iff $\sigma(n)$ is odd, so this is equivalent to just asking what even $n$ make $\sigma(n)$ odd. Some examples that aren't of the form you suggest are 18, 200, 98, but with a slight modification your condition is correct.

@ZoeAllen Is there a mathematical formula describing numbers in the "modification" you speak of? Also, do they get rarer as the numbers get larger?

For any positive integer $n$, $\sigma(n)$ is odd if and only if $n$ is either a square or twice a square.

Oh, cool! Is there a mathematical justification for why that is (and would you like to post it as an answer so I can credit you for that)?

Geoffrey Trang's comment is easy to prove: $\sigma$ is multiplicative so you just have to consider the cases of prime powers...
